# Service context not working as ApplicationContext

Tags: android

I have a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that catches Google Cloud Messages and starts an IntentService to handle the incoming message.  In the IntentService, I need to get access to a singleton  SQLite database. Normally,  I  open the database from an Activity with getApplicationContext(), but that throws errors and gives an NPE sometimes when opened from the IntentService. If the app has been backgrounded for a long time, when a message arrives and the intent service needs access to the DB, it crashes.  If the app has just recently been backgrounded, the DB is accessible and
everything works fine.

My question is this:

What Context should I be passing to insure the database is properly opened?  Since IntentService is a subclass of Context, I've tried passing in just 'this', passing in the BaseContext() and even the ApplicationContext().

### WakefulBroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

    Log.i("Receiver", "Getting Data: "+intent.toString());
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

### IntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private static triDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private final static String GAME_ID = "game_id=";
private static OnActiveGameNotifyListener listener = null;
private static int currentUserId;
private static String currentUserName;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
    mDbHelper = new triDbAdapter(this.getBaseContext());
    mDbHelper.open();                                     //   <-- Fails here


   // depending on what the Intent contains, I need to send notifications that include 
   // various items from thte database when the notification is created.  I need to know
   // the opponent's name, the score, etc. so the notification can say "Joe scored..."
    currentUserId = mDbHelper.getUserId();    
    currentUserName = mDbHelper.getName();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
<snip>
}
```

### Database

```
 public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;

        public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {

            // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
            // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
            // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
            if (mInstance == null) {
              mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext()); // <-- fail here
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
         * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
        */
        private DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

 /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public  triDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

 public triDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
```

### StackTrace

```
    12-17 12:26:28.254    6888-6888/com.ulsanonline.triominoes I/Receiver﹕ Getting Data: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.ulsanonline.triominoes cmp=com.ulsanonline.triominoes/.GcmIntentService (has extras) }
12-17 12:26:28.264    6888-6888/com.ulsanonline.triominoes E/GcmIntentService﹕ STACKTRACE: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:267)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.ulsanonline.triominoes.triDbAdapter.open(triDbAdapter.java:430)
            at com.ulsanonline.triominoes.GcmIntentService.<init>(GcmIntentService.java:57)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2713)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1361)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Are you closing the DB anywhere?

Comment: "If the app has been backgrounded for a long time, when a message arrives and the intent service needs access to the DB, it crashes" -- most likely, your process was terminated during that "long time". "What Context should I be passing to insure the database is properly opened?" -- I'd use `getApplicationContext()`, in case any of the `SQLite*` classes hold onto the context, so that you don't leak it. Beyond that, while pointing out "Fails here" is nice, we really need the stack trace.

Comment: well, it turns out, where I do the work makes a difference. When I put the database open stuff in the constructor, it fails upon msg receipt if the app is no longer running and not visible in 'recents'.  However, if I open the database and pull out what I need when in onHandleIntent(), then everything is fine. I can kill the backgrounded app and when the receiver   gets a new msg, onHandleIntent seems to have a different idea of what the context is.  Any idea why that would be so?